# Name an element with the name of its XSLT attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for XLST to edit an xml file. As explained in the title, I would like to rename my items with the name of their "name" attribute.

My xml file :

```xml
<doe name="titi">
    <bob name="toto">blabla</bob>
    <bob name="tutu">blabla </bob>
</doe>
```

The output xml file that I would like:

```xml
<titi>
    <toto>blabla</toto>
    <tutu>blabla </tutu>
</titi>
```

I tried several things but I was sent back an "attribute" name "hab a bad value"

```xml
<xsl:element name="@bob">
    <xsl:value-of select="$bob" />  
</xsl:element>
```

or

```xml
<xsl:element name="/doe/@bob">
    <xsl:value-of select="$bob" />  
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code as your requirment

```
<xsl:template match="doe">
<xsl:element name="{@name}">
<xsl:for-each select="bob">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@name]">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
```

Check transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYj7

Comment: Of course, it will only work if the value of the attribute is a valid XML element name.